# OracleSolaris 11.2 and bit operations

Tags: bit-manipulation, solaris, opensolaris

Are there any standard bit manipulation routines/macros available, e.g. SETBIT, CLEARBIT-like. I found atomic bit operations in `man -s9f atomic_bits`, is there anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: Try Bit Twiddling: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: I'm aware of Bit Twiddling, but I thought there could be already something available in Solaris, so one doesn't need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Short answer - no.  Solaris is an amalgam of previous flavors of UNIX, like BSD.  This is evident by the /usr/ucb directory - name for the Univ of California Berkeley.  You find whoami there for instance.  The presumption was/is that most of the standard C stuff available in /usr/include would fly for almost any development.  Any new stuff is up to you.  Use bit hacks and create your own include files.

Comment: There are a few macros in sys/sysmacros.h

Comment: @Liam, those are useful macros, but I didn't find macros to set/clear specific bits.